# Regular Expression (REGEX) to match : or . or '

Tags: php, regex

i want to use regex to check if i have ' or . or :

i should add ? before it

for example

Rue de l'etrang

should be like this

Rue de l?'etrang

or

Rue de l'etrang: nancy

should be like this

Rue de l?'etrang?: nancy

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple regex :

```
'|\.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code for testing a match:

```
$str = 'Rue de l\'etrang';
if(preg_match('/[:\'.]/i', $str))
{ 
    echo 'found match';
}
else
{
    echo 'match not found';
}
```